# Cannot use std::map::emplace to insert an object of a class with no copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++14, copy-constructor, stdmap

I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <map>
#include <condition_variable>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(): m_cv() {}
    std::condition_variable m_cv; //just to illustrate that a copy constructor is not obvious to write
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string,MyClass> testmap;
    testmap.emplace("key",MyClass());
}
```

Compilation fails at the last line (`emplace` method call) with a very long error that starts as follows:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair, MyClass>::pair(const char [4], MyClass)
```

By trial and error, I have come up with the understanding that the error comes from the absence of copy constructor for `MyClass`. If I add one, or else if I replace the condition variable attribute with a basic type (`int` for instance), the error disappears. However I'm not sure of my analysis, and most importantly, I do not understand why a copy constructor for `MyClass` is needed here.

So my question is twofold:

1. Why is the copy constructor required?
2. How can I rewrite my code in order not to need the copy constructor (which is kind of tricky to write due to the complexity of the class, omitted here for brevity)?

Comment: I think you need to supply a std::string not a string literal to emplace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++17:

```
testmap.try_emplace("key");
```

In C++14 or older:

```
testmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple("key"), std::tuple<>{});
```

---

You code constructs `MyClass` twice: one time you do it manually (`MyClass()`), and the second time `std::map` does it internally (in your case it tries to call the copy constructor).

The second constructor call isn't going anywhere, but you can change what arguments it receives, if any. So you have to get rid of the first call, and change the second call to receive no arguments, as opposed to `const MyClass &`.

The arguments of `.emplace()` go straight to [the constructor of `std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair). If you examine the constructors, the only one that can default-construct the second element (not counting the pair's own default constructor) seems to be the `std::piecewise_construct` one.

And [`.try_emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) just uses `std::piecewise_construct` internally.